# How to make some Django Inlines Read Only

Tags: django, inline

I'm using django admin and adding a `TabularInline` to my ModelAdmin class.  Think `Author` and the inline is `Books`.  How do I make some of those inlines appear read only and some appear editable based on certain characteristics of the model instance for each specific inline?  Say I wanted all the books written before 2001 to be read only.  And all the books written after that to be editable.

I've tried overriding `has_change_permission()` on the TablularInline and using the `obj` param, but it is receiving the parent and not the instance of this specific inline.

Comment: Are you overriding `has_change_permission()` on the ModelAdmin or its TabularInline?

Comment: @NickODell good question.  I've updated the question to point out that I'm overriding it on the Inline and not the Parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override your inline form and check the value on the instance in the `__init__()`.

Example:

```
class AuthorBookInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Book

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and self.instance.created_ts.year <= 2001:
            for f in self.fields:
                  self.fields[f].widget.attrs['readonly'] = 'readonly'
```

Don't forget to set the form value on your inline...

```
class AuthorBookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    form = AuthorBookInlineForm
    extra = 0
```

Comment: Here's where I'm having trouble.  obj is the parent and not the instance for that inline.  Seems like a bug for 11 years or so.  https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15602

Comment: I've been doing this wrong for years.

Answer (score 0):

In Django >= 2.1 (afaik)

You have to override your inline form and check the value on the instance in the **init**().

Disabling a field by setting `self.fields['field'].disabled = true`

Example:

```
class AuthorBookInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Book

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and self.instance.created_ts.year <= 2001:
            for f in self.fields:
                  self.fields[f].disabled = true
```

Don't forget to set the form value on your inline:

```
class AuthorBookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    form = AuthorBookInlineForm
    extra = 0
```